# Django Rest check if object in ManyToMany field

Tags: python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-views

When I make a list of projects, duplicates appear, those that have more than one member
Here is my code.

models.py

```
class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="project_owner_set"
    )
    member = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="project_member_set")
```

serializers.py

```
class ProjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owner = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        queryset=User.objects.all(), slug_field="username", required=False
    )
    member = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        queryset=User.objects.all(), slug_field="username", many=True
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ["name", "owner", "member", "id"]
        read_only_fields = ["id"]
```

views.py

```
class ProjectListView(ListAPIView):
    queryset = Project.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProjectSerializer
    user_field = "owner"

    def get_queryset(self):
        
        return (
            super()
            .get_queryset()
            .filter(Q(owner=self.request.user) | Q(member=self.request.user))
        )
```

permissions.py

```
class ProjectIsOwnerOrReadOnly(permissions.BasePermission):
    """
    This permission checks if the request user is the owner of a Project object. Otherwise it only allows safe methods.
    """

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        if request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
            return True

        # Write permissions are only allowed to the owner of the blog.
        return obj.owner == request.user
```

url:http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/tasks/projects/

code result

`{ "name": "Proyecto test 3", "owner": "aik", "member": [ "aioko", "aiko" ], "id": 3 }, { "name": "Proyecto test 3", "owner": "aik", "member": [ "aioko", "aiko" ], "id": 3 }, { "name": "Prueba proyecto sin miembro", "owner": "aik", "member": [], "id": 8 }, { "name": "Prueba proyecto sin miembro", "owner": "aiko", "member": [ "aioko", "aik" ], "id": 13 } }`

I hope that when I make a listing they only bring me the projects that I am a member or owner of.